# Unity: Move PNG from outside the camera to the Game Scene (Slide-In transition)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in Unity and now I have a little scene with some Buttons in 2D. I want two PNG-files (sprites) to move into the screen from left to right and right to left. The game starts and within the process those two objects slide into the screen simultaneously out of nowhere.

How can I make that possible?

I would be very grateful for every answer :)

Edit: That is how it looks like. Actually it is a big piece of cheese and has to be shown completely and a little further up.

Comment: You'd need go get the screen position bounds converted to world space, take half the offset of your objects bounding size, then start your objects at the edge of your screen in world position with the offset. Use Mathf.PingPong either in update or in a coroutine to get the back and forth motion. I can add a more in depth answer a bit later if you need - currently on mobile.

Comment: A more in depth answer would be helpful :D
I understood like 30% of it hahaha

Comment: Just to clarify, you have two 2D sprites, not UI images that you want to moving from the right side to the left side of the screen and then back once?

Comment: Just re-reading the question as I had misread it, you just want two images moving inward from offscreen? Do they need to be sprites or can they be UI images? As to make sure these images fit the screen or go exactly where you need with changing resolutions, it would be easier to use UI with anchor points.

Comment: Exactly. I have two images (png files) and I want them to move into the screen from offscreen

Comment: The answer I posted should do that.

Comment: Yeah that should make sense. However, how can I make the png move to a certain position of the game screen? Like on 25% of the left side an not in the middle. Is there a way to adjust that?

Comment: Yes. Try using the snippet I provided. The field `goalPos` is a literal position that the objects will move to. Each one is set up individually, I just happened to set them all to the same position for the gif I showed. If you want a specific % to by your goal position, you can use the viewport coordinate space. You can just convert these % of your viewport to your goal position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you will want to position your objects relative to the view port coordinates, then offset this position by the extents of your renderer's bounds. In other words, move the object right to the edge of your screen, then move it completely off as centering it on the edge will show it half way on screen.

```
public enum StartingPlacement
{
    TOP,
    BOTTOM,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{  
    [SerializeField] private float startDelay = 1;
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCam = null;                                 // main camera
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] [SerializeField] private float goalPosX;                    // the % of the viewport of our X
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] [SerializeField] private float goalPosY;                    // the % of the viewport of our Y
    [SerializeField] private float timeToReachGoal = 2.0f;                          // the time it takes us to reach goal pos from our starting position
    [SerializeField] private StartingPlacement placement = StartingPlacement.LEFT;  // which direction we are starting from
    [Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] [SerializeField] private float offset = 0.0f;               // the other axis our start position will be % of the view port (ex: top is 1.0f Y, but is this value X)
    [SerializeField] private Renderer rend = null;                                  // renderer of this object

    private float zPosStart = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (rend == null)
            rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (mainCam == null)
            mainCam = Camera.main;

        // save our z position
        zPosStart = transform.position.z;

        // set our starting position based on the bounds of our camera and the bounds of our renderer
        SetInitialPosition();

        // now start our movement to the goal position
        StartCoroutine(MoveToGoalPostiion());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the initial position of our object based on the viewport position and the size of the renderer
    /// </summary>
    private void SetInitialPosition()
    {
        // with viewport coordinates, (0,0) is the bottom left and (1,1) is the top right
        // I am also assuming the starting position is half way up or across the screen - change teh 0.5 to alter it

        // we also need to offset our current position by +/- the X or Y of half the bounds of our renderer
        switch (placement)
        {
            case StartingPlacement.TOP:
                transform.position = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(offset, 1.0f, mainCam.transform.position.z));
                transform.position += new Vector3(0f, rend.bounds.extents.y, 0f);
                break;
            case StartingPlacement.BOTTOM:
                transform.position = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(offset, 0.0f, mainCam.transform.position.z));
                transform.position += new Vector3(0f, -rend.bounds.extents.y, 0f);
                break;
            case StartingPlacement.LEFT:
                transform.position = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0f, offset, mainCam.transform.position.z));
                transform.position += new Vector3(-rend.bounds.extents.x, 0f, 0f);
                break;
            case StartingPlacement.RIGHT:
                transform.position = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0f, offset, mainCam.transform.position.z));
                transform.position += new Vector3(rend.bounds.extents.x, 0f, 0f);
                break;
        }

        // set our start back to our original Z
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, zPosStart);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Move from our current position to our goal position
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator MoveToGoalPostiion()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startDelay);
        Vector2 startPos = transform.position;

        float currentTime = 0.0f;

        // create our goal position
        Vector3 goalPos = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(goalPosX, goalPosY, mainCam.transform.position.z));

        goalPos.z = zPosStart;

        while (currentTime <= timeToReachGoal)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, goalPos, currentTime / timeToReachGoal);
            currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        // set our position in case of floating point precision issues
        transform.position = goalPos;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the script working:

[image: Example]

All four sprites start off screen and will move towards their goal, which is the center of the screen. I also added some functionality such as the enum specifying which direction of the screen would be coming from and an offset to allow you to control the nondirectional axis starting position. Let me know if you have questions.

Edit: Something else to add on, I am using `SerializeField` for all of the fields along with the `private` keyword. All this means is that Unity will serialize the field, but they can not be accessed by other scripts. Simply assign the values you want on the script itself, not in code.

Edit 2: I updated the code to be even simpler so less assignment is needed. Here is a gif of the script in use showing it can be uncentered. I also added null checks so you do not need to actually assign anything in the inspector aside from the float values. You can leave the camera and the renderer blank if you like as long as the script is on a renderer and the scene has a `Camera.main`.

[image: Second example]

Edit 3: Here is a little more in-depth explanation for the switch statement. To understand how I came to the solution, I will explain how I understood your problem. You had wanted to move objects of some unknown size from the edge of the screen to a given point on the screen over time. In Unity, there are various different coordinate spaces you can work with, one of which is the viewport space.

I thought of using this space that ranges from [0.0, 1.0] (bottom left to top right) that defines the coordinates on the current camera's viewport. The function [`ViewportToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html) will convert a position on the viewport to a world position. Now that I have a built-in function that can do all the heavy lifting, I need to set up some sort of conditional to handle how it can be used.

To me, the simplest way to describe how the movement occurs is by deciding which direction (top, bottom, left, or right) the object will originate from, then give it some sort of offset relative to the direction.

For example, if an object is coming from the left direction, the offset would affect its height coming from the left direction. As I am still using viewport, the offset will range from [0.0,1.0] being at the lowest point on the left to the highest.

With this information, I have the basis for the start of the switch cases by having the enum

`TOP BOTTOM LEFT RIGHT`.

Respectively, the viewport coordinates would be

`[offset, 1.0] [offset 0.0] [0.0 offset] [1.0 offset]`.

Now the coordinates are starting in a good position, but they are starting halfway on the screen which is not what is expected. The reason for this is because the pivot point by default of sprites is the center. To fix this, you can either change the pivot of the import image but this would lead to unexpected behavior elsewhere, or you can account for it with another offset.

After setting the position relative to the viewport, simply take half of the size of the renderer and offset it depending on the direction you are coming from. Meaning if you are trying to be on the left, you need to add half of the renderer width, while on the right, you would subtract it. Combining both the viewport offset along with the offset from half the renderer will give you the end result of the switch statement. At the end, I am also setting the Z component of the position as the viewport will make this coordinate get a bit funky.

Comment: Thank you! Now how can I do it for my specific PNG? Which variable/value shall I replace?
(Sorry for my probably stupid questions :D)

Comment: @Big_F No worries. You just need to add this script to your PNG Sprite, then drag in the object under the field `rend`. You'll also need to assign the other fields so it will work. Let me know if you are unsure how to assign those as well.

Comment: @Big_F Did you end up getting this working? As the snippet I provided should do what you want as I tested it.

Comment: No I didn't :D
I am a complete noob 

Comment: @Big_F What part did you not get working? Or what do you not understand? I can append more info to help out.

Comment: How do i drag the object under the field "rend" and which other fields do I need to assign? :D

Comment: Oo gotcha - when I'm back from the gym I'll add a gif on how to use the script.

Comment: @Big_F Alright post is updated - let me know if that works.

Comment: When I start it in Unity I get many errors of the kind "The type or namespace name 'SerializeFieldAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and others like RequireComponent and SerializeField etc.
You don't have discord or sth like that do you? :D

Comment: You need to include `using UnityEngine;` and `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of the file. I didn't include them as I assumed you'd know they are needed.

Comment: Now it says: "Using the generic type 'IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments" lol

Comment: Also use `using System.Collections;`

Comment: I would like to post a screenshot but now it kinda works. The object slides in into the bottom left corner and the PNG is shown like almost half of it and not completely :D

Comment: Did you set values that make sense? You can edit your question and add extra information

Comment: I edited my comment with a screenshot. I kinda changed some values but then it started scrolling from right to left showing the same end result like in the screenshot.
As weird as it sounds, it would be helpful if we could talk :D

Comment: Yea you need go change the end values X and Y. Right now they're probably both 0,0

Comment: Well I messed around a little bit but I only got to the point where it moves from the top to the bottom or from right to left and showing half of the PNG. But I don't think that this is the way to go. I think it's not right to rely on some random guesses but give it a logical solution.
Do you have time for like 30 minutes so we can fix it via screensharing? :D

Comment: Sorry don't do screen sharing or calling. You can add a screen shot of the current image selected so I can see the values.

Comment: Oh okay.
You can see a new screenshot in the main question. The result is the same as it was. With these values it appears very quick from right to left but again in the bottom corner and not a little higher and more to the right with the full object.

Comment: I am thinking about to just make a video of it and to generate the buttons after the video is finished. The video would include the moving objects and effects. I couldn't handle it how the video starts first after clicking on the play button of unity. After the video plays I have some buttons which brings me to other menus.

Comment: Alright so ye thats why it's wrong. Do **NOT** edit the code I gave you it works as is. It's also not correct as the values of view space work from [0.0,1.0]. Undo the edits you made and change those values in the inspector like I showed in my gif. I had even written this in the comment of the code you had posted.

Comment: Oh lol now I see 
Anyways. I played with the values and I almost get to the point where I want to have it but is that the right way? Are there any mathematical solutions for it?
In the end it has to look like in the screenshot I added.
The easiest solution would actually be with a video I created which starts at the beginning and stops and the last frame of it still remains.

Comment: The vales are 0.0 to 1.0 of the screen bottom to top left to right. The values represent % of the screen so you can figure it out that way.

Comment: Alright I made it with the PNG on the left and I have a PNG which is kinda mirrorlike so it comes from right outside of the screen and slides to the left which I also managed to do. The "problem" is that it is a little higher than in my initial project. By moving the sprite nothing changed. Does a change in the code need to be done? I just want them to be on the same Y-position

Comment: You mean the start or the end? All of this can be changed from editing the fields in the inspector of the script you will not need to change any code

Comment: Ah nevermind I am lost. I can handle it with the offset thing which I didn't understand :D

Anyway. There is a third object which comes in first before the other two come in. It also features an audio. How can I make that "sequential"? Like starting with one PNG and after like 3 seconds the two others at the same time.
How about we do a private chat since this is getting long here and shifts into another direction? :D

Comment: Well, that almost seems like another question entirely. Your current question has been answered by my post. You can upvote / accept this answer to close it, then ask a new question as it is somewhat different.

Comment: Yeah true. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can u explain a little bit what happens in the switch cases?
I mean, I would never have come up with that solution :D Maybe at the example with LEFT

Comment: @Big_F Just need some clarification, are you just asking to understand how the switch works and how each case works? I can add a blurb if this is what you'd like.

Comment: @Big_F I added a longer explanation for the switch statement. Let me know if you still need a little more help.

Comment: Oh cool!
Yeah. Is it possible to give them a delay? Like 2 seconds before they start moving. I know, I could adjust that by increasing the time until they reach the goal position but that way the objects would move slower.

Comment: @Big_F Yea definitely possible. I can add it to the answer, it is 1 line of code. - Edit; Added

Comment: Oh lol :D
Thanks hahah
I'll try it out :)